# MySql; proper way to update fields of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, field

When trying to describe a table I get a table with missing information (see first table); what would be the best way to update that table in a way that looks like the second one? My SQL background is not so strong, so I'd love to hear ideas on how to do this

First table (how it is actually)

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| config_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| scope     | varchar(8)       | NO   |     | default |       |
| scope_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| path      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | general |       |
| value     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Second table (how it should be)

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| config_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| scope     | varchar(8)       | NO   | MUL | default |                |
| scope_id  | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| path      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | general |                |
| value     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see following differences between the two tables :

- column `config_id` should be `auto_increment` and also `primary key` of the table
- a (non-unique) index is missing on column `scope`

The following statement should change the table as required :

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable 
    MODIFY COLUMN config_id INT auto_increment,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (config_id),
    ADD INDEX idx_scope(scope)
;
```

PS : `DEFAULT NULL` does not make sense for `config_id` : since it is a primary key, your RDBMS will never allow it to be set to `NULL`.

Please note that this answer is based on the information you provided only. Running this statement will not necessarily make the table structures strictly equivalent, since there could be other differences that can not be seen in the representation that you provided. You can get a complete DDL statement describing the table using the `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` syntax.

Comment: Hi; thanks for the input; Default should be NULL for config_id; can that also be included in the query?

Comment: @Eduardo : `DEFAULT NULL` actually does not make sense for a primary key, since it will never allow `NULL` values anyway...